# Change color of subgroup in ggplot boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've drawn up a grouped boxplot (=Attribut) in R using ggplot with subgroups for each Attribut (=Produkt). As the colors per subgroup are too similar, I would like to change the colors but so far I've been unable to do so.

This is my script:

```
library(ggplot2)
jpeg(file="Sensorik.jpeg",height=300,width=600)
ggplot(df_1, aes(x=Attribut, y=Rating, fill=factor(Produkt)))+
  geom_boxplot(colour="black")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,face="bold",size=16),
        plot.margin=margin(20,30,20,30),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1,9,by=1),limits=c(1,9))+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Produkt",labels=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size=14),legend.text = element_text(size=12))+
  labs(x="Attribut",y="Rating")
dev.off()
```

So far I have tried using Rcolorbrewer inserting the following line:

```
scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1",name="Produkt")+
```

But this didn't change anything. So, I have tried changing the colors manually:

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "darkblue", "green","yellow","lightblue","orange"))+
```

But I received the following error message:

> Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill',
> which will replace the existing scale.

Comment: If you're already using a factor to fill, you don't need `scale_fill_discrete()`. Remove that and use **either** `scale_fill_brewer()` - **not** `scale_color_brewer()` - or `scale_fill_manual()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I additionally moved the legend labels to scale_fill_brewer() and then it worked perfectly!